# Edit search form with a module

Tags: forms

I have made and installed a new module, called searchIcon.
The problem is I want to edit the default value "Search" next to the search form.
I tried the code below, but it does not seem to work.

```
<?php

/*
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */

function searchIcon_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value']= 'TESTSEARCH';
    }
}

?>
```

How could I change the text "search" to e.g. "TESTSEARCH"?

Comment: That code should work, supposing that it is placed in the *searchIcon.module* file. Are you getting any error?

Comment: It is. However, it doesn't work. FYI. This is in my searchIcon.info.yml :

name: Search Icon
type: module
description: 'This module replaces search value by an icon'
version: VERSION
core: 8.x
configure: searchIcon.form

Comment: Module und theme machine names must only contain lower case letters and underscores.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but you have also enabled the module right?

Comment: Uppercase characters only cause issues with `hook_update_N()`, not other hooks. While it's preferable to avoid uppercase characters, they would not cause issues in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think there must have been a typo somewhere or something, but anyway, this setup works:

info yaml:

```
name: Search Icon
description: This module replaces search value by an icon.

type: module
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

module:

```
<?php    

/*
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */    

function searchIcon_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value']= 'TESTSEARCH';
    }    
}
```

Please note that the module does not work as intended yet, the value should be replaced by an html decimal code for the desired icon.